# how to override float using @media?

Tags: html, css

So I wanted my nav bar to have 3 links with each link being to the left,center and right (http://lawthatworks.com/site/) so I decided to target each with a float. My problem is when my site is viewed on a mobile or tablet, the responsive menu is not showing properly because of the float tags. How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Move this whole section

```
#menu-item-12{
    float:left;
}
#menu-item-11{
    float:right;
}
#menu-item-13{
    float:center;
}
```

Into a media query using the existing breakpoint `(min-width: 850px)` this will mean that if the screen is bigger than 850px wide it will float otherwise it wont

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 850px ) {
    #menu-item-12 {
        float: left;
    }
    #menu-item-11 {
        float: right;
    }
    #menu-item-13 {
        float: center;
    }
}
```

But [the use of floats in layout is discouraged](http://designshack.net/articles/css/farewell-floats-the-future-of-css-layout/). I would recommend using [the flexible box model layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Set the parent as `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between;` This will align all items spaced equidistant from each other.

```
@media screen and ( min-width: 850px ) {
    #menu-home-menu {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
}
```

While both methods will display the same in most modern browser, they are buggy. It is generally a good idea to stay away from them, unless you're doing something like adding an image to a paragraph and letting the text "float" around the image.

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 how would you do it the way you recommend? I fairly new so im trying to find the best way to do thing.